# Is is safe to manipulate a std::mutex belonging to a std::unique_ptr from a const qualified class method?

Tags: c++, mutex

I need a class that is both copyable and whose private members are mutexed. Is is safe to manipulate a std::mutex belonging to a std::unique_ptr from a `const` qualified class method? Is there a better solution for providing thread safety of the members while at the same time being copyable?

```
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>

class test
{
    test(const test &source) {
        set(source.get());
    }

    int get() const
    {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> guard(*m.get());
        return i;
    }

    void set(int i)
    {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> guard(*m.get());
        this->i = i;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> m = std::make_unique<std::mutex>();
    int i = 0;
};
```

Live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/3oWhEz4on)

Comment: I don't see a need for that `unique_ptr`. Just plain `std::mutex` as a data member should work just fine.

Comment: FWIW, `test` isn't copyable.  It is moveable though.

Comment: @PeteBecker Doing that makes the class no longer copyable or moveable.

Comment: It is no more safer and no more dangerous than modifying it in a non-`const` class method.

Comment: @NathanOliver -- it's not moveable or copyable with the compiler-generated operators. Writing a copy constructor and an assignment operator that ignore the mutex makes it copyable. Same for moveable.

Comment: Just use `mutable std::mutex m` and you are fine https://godbolt.org/z/9rcr7rTvK

Comment: Why not just use `std::atomic<int>` instead and get rid of the `std::mutex`?

Comment: As @MarekR points out, my "just plain `std::mutex`" isn't quite right. It should be "just plain `mutable std::mutex`".

Comment: @Marek R you are right, this (using the `mutable` keyword) is the solution. No need for std::unique_ptr!

Comment: That last comment has me puzzled. I can see `mutable` countering `const`, but what were you using `std__unique_ptr` for that could be resolved with `mutable`?

Comment: @user4581301 it was needed to be able to pass a `class test` instance as a lambda argument, and have this lambda convertible to a std::function

Comment: Got you. You were trying to avoid copying the mutex.